# How to trigger an animation when UIScrollView is scrolled to maxY? SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, triggers, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view and I want an animation to start when the scrollview is scrolled to its end and a little bit further (+75 px). How is that possible? I thought about an if-condition (if view.bounds.maxy >= 1075). But how can this condition or function be called when the user scrolls?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/ has a callback for when the scrollview scrolls

Comment: You should check the contentOffset property (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) and compare it with contentSize (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize). This should be done in scrollViewDidScroll delegate call.

Comment: Ok, thats helpful. Thank you. Is there an opposite of scrollviewdidscrolltotop? I can´t find one.

Comment: As you can see here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScrollToTop:), there isn't. Top means 0 offset and is present in protocol because it can be done by tapping the status bar (if scrollView has scrollsToTop property set to YES).

Comment: ok, so I will do it as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your ViewController is a subclass of `UIScrollViewDelegate`. Next, you want to set your scrollView's delegate to self in the `ViewDidLoad()`. Then, you'll want to use `scrollViewDidScroll()` and handle things from there.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 75.0 {
        // Your animation code goes HERE... //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your scroll to go further than the actual visible content, consider adding the required distance (+75px in your case) to the contentSize. This will enable the content to scroll further.

As for the animation, UIScrollViewDelegate has multiple methods that can help you. You can keep a check like:

```
if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height {
    // Animation code
}
```